# React Selecting dropdown option multiple times

Tags: reactjs

I am wanting to be able to select a language I have called "Skip" more than one time without it disappearing from the dropdown. Currently, any language I select will disappear from the dropdown. Is this possible? Here's my code:

```
const languages = [
    { key: 'skip', text: 'Skip', value: 'Skip' },
    { key: 'english', text: 'English', value: 'English' },
    { key: 'french', text: 'French', value: 'French' },
]

handleAudioInputChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState( {  [name]: value })

<Form.Select fluid search label='Audio Channels' name='audiochannelsValue' value={audiochannelsValue} options={languages}  placeholder='Choose Audio Channels' onChange={this.handleAudioInputChange} multiple = "true"/>
```

I've tried multiple things such as hideSelectedOptions = {false}, but this does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? I don't understand the use-case you have nor what you mean by saying that it disappears from the dropdown.

Comment: @Chris I am wanting to make it so the user can select options English/Skip/French/Skip (in other words, they can select Skip multiple times)

Comment: And what happens when they select the Skip option twice? Do you want to have a counter counting the times pressed? Explain the desired implementation too.

Comment: Can you give me the desired new state **after** the user has selected English/Skip/French/Skip?

Comment: I am going to do a database insert that would look something like this English/Skip/French/Skip (in other words, itll just take all of the dropdown selected items and turn it into a string

Comment: Okay, so the result can be a string that gives the order of the items selected?

Comment: correct! @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want a string based on the user input, you could do:

```
handleAudioInputChange = (e, { value }) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const newVal = `${prevState.audiochannelsValue.length ? '/' : ''}${value}`;
    return {
      textValue: prevState.textValue.concat(newVal),
      audiochannelsValue: value
    };
  });
}
```

This will build a string based on the previous state and separate each value with `/`. Haven't tested it, but it should generate (in order):

```
English
English/Skip
English/Skip/French
English/Skip/French/Skip
```

Comment: This displays nothing in the dropdown menu. Any idea how to keep the current view of the dropdown menu?

Comment: @Jay266 Oh sorry, forgot that one. Try my modified example above